# How to avoid for-if-else hell in n iterations using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

For example I have this code:

```
var Foo = [1,2,3,4];

function searchInFoo(n) {
    for(var i = 0, arrayLength = Foo.length; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if(Foo[i] === n) {
            console.log("N: " + n + " found!");
        } else {
            console.log("N: " + n + " not found!");
        }
    }
}


searchInFoo(4);
```

Well, as I have expected I Foo array with n elements I have also n iterations of for loop. That's cool.  So, if I call searchInFoo function with any n parameter, my function will also execute all blocks in if else statement n times. For example, in upper example I have once logged "n found", and thrice "N: n not found!".

What is the best approach to avoid execution in else block, without loosing some basic error catching functionality, what actually happens when I omit whole else block like here:

```
var Foo = [1,2,3,4];

function searchInFoo(n) {
    for(var i = 0, arrayLength = Foo.length; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if(Foo[i] === n) {
            console.log("N: " + n + " found!");
        } 
    }
}


searchInFoo(1);
```

Comment: If you omit the `else` block and the test is false then the code inside the if-block is skipped and the for-loop continues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the loop in this case:

```
var foo = [1,2,3,4];

function searchInFoo(n) {
    if(foo.indexOf(n) > -1) {
        console.log("N: " + n + " found!");
    } 
}
searchInFoo(1);
```

*Note: don't capitalize variable names, leave that for constructor functions.*

Or, even simpler:

```
function searchInFoo(n) {
    return foo.indexOf(n) > -1;
}
console.log(searchInFoo(1) ? 'found' : 'not found');
```

---

Upon reading your question again, I believe you're looking for something more generic, like [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (polyfills available on MDN). How about a function that iterates through a given array, and runs a function on each item?

```
function myforeach(arr, fn) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        fn(arr[i]);
    }
}
myforeach([1,2,3], function(el) {
    console.log(el === 1);
}); // logs true, false, false
```

A custom `map` function would be very similar:

```
function mymap(arr, fn) {
    var retArray = [];
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        retArr.push(fn(arr[i]));
    }
    return retArray;
}
var validated = myforeach([1,2,3], function(el) {
    return el === 1;
}); // returns [true, false, false]
```

Comment: Note that Array.indexOf is part of the ECMA5 spec, and will thus not work on older browsers. You can use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) if desired

Comment: Yeah, I always forget that. Such a basic method... and it's been available for strings from the beginning. Anyway, now that you linked to the polyfill, this answer is complete! :-) Thanks.

Comment: @bfavaretto
I forgot to mention, that I use similar expression on objects, iterating through all objects pushed in temporary array, than logging property of object where met conditions, like here:

´code´if(n === Foo[i].someProperty)´code´

Comment: @bfavaretto Running function on every item in array didn't crossed my mind at all. I was convinced that there is native way escaping else block.

Comment: @AlanKis Are you actually looking for `return` or `break`? The first will break out of the loop and the function, the second will only break out of the loop.

Comment: @bfavaretto I'm confused more then I was before. Here is scenario, i have n objects, I have putted that objects in array for easier handling. Then I perform evaluation on every object specified property value and given argument in function and saved true in variable hits. If hits equal true, print out whole object at [i] index in temporary array, if not print out some error mesagge. Point is that I have to use for loop so I can catch all indexes in array and also give parameter value, which is string in my cause in function call, not in body.

Comment: Okay, `return` and `break` in a loop are useful if you want to abort the loop in the middle (like when you're looking for a value, and already found it). No the case here then, since you want to loop through all objects in the array. Your scenario sounds like the perfect use case for `map` (linked in my answer). I edited the answer with an example of a custom map-like function, I hope it helps! @AlanKis